# How can i simplify this into one line

Tags: c#, linq

```
portalSelectslist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId).AccessTypePortalId = item.AccesstypePortalId;
                portalSelectslist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId).Isselected = true;
```

Update an item from list i update each property in each line instead of that how can i update both in a line

Comment: Don't put a newline after the first line's semicolon?

Comment: This really should be *three (3)* lines: first one saving the result of `FirstOrDefault`, and then two more to do the assignments. Trying shove things into one line is just going to hurt readability, and searching for it twice is more work than necessary.

Comment: I need to update the item in the list.

Comment: That's fine. But don't search for the item twice.

Comment: Also, don't use `FirstOrDefault` without first checking for `null`... if it doesn't find the item, you have a `NullReferenceException` on your hands. If you know you have at least one matching item, use `First` so it throws an exception *there* when it fails. The condition will be easier to debug because the exception will be more meaningful and lead you more directly to the cause.

Comment: I'm going to say this again, because it bears repeating: Trying to shove things into one line is going to hurt readability. You should be more focused on refactoring your code so that your functions do one thing and do it well, and then composing those to perform a slightly larger thing and do it well, and so on.

Comment: Is there any way to update a item form list like this
                portalSelectslist.Where(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId).ToList().ForEach(s => s.AccessTypePortalId = item.AccesstypePortalId ==1&& s.Isselected = true);

Comment: Definitely ***not*** like that. What you're trying to do is a *Bad Idea™*.

Comment: And see my previous comment where I explain why it's a bad idea and what you should be doing instead.

Comment: NO, NO, NO!!!! You do not seem to understand how variables and reference types work!!!

Comment: Unless you have misrepresented your question both answers below will perform the updates to an item in the list as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't or probably shouldn't. Just because it's on a single line, doesn't make it better code.

The following is much more readable/maintainable.

```
var portal = portalSelectslist
    .FirstOrDefault(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId);

if (portal != null) {
    portal.AccessTypePortalId = item.AccesstypePortalId;
    portal.Isselected = true;
}
```

**UPDATE**
Technically you could do this in a single "line" but don't. This code is not easy to read or understand and therefore much less maintainble.

```
portalSelectslist.Where(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId).ToList().ForEach(s => { s.AccessTypePortalId = item.AccesstypePortalId; s.Isselected = true });
```

Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

The code looks like it's updating *all* values that match the where clause. This is not the intent you're trying to convey to whomever is reading the code, you only want to update a single value.

The first thing to worry about writing code (after getting it working) is readability and maintainability.

Comment: What if `portal` is null?

Comment: It'll fail, just like the original code with a NullReferenceException. But yeah, there should be guard code checking `portal` for null.

Comment: I need to update a item in th elist

Comment: It does, `portal` is a reference to the same item that is also in the list.

Comment: NO! You do not need to update the reassign the item back to the list. You really need to understand how variables and reference types work. Once you have a ___reference___ to the item (`portal`) then updating any properties will also update the properties of the item in the list IT IS THE SAME INSTANCE OF THE SAME OBJECT!!!!!!

Comment: Before worrying about "minifying" code, perhaps you should take some time to learn the basics.

Answer (score 2):

Use a temporary variable. So you don't have to query the list twice and it's easier to read.

```
var temp = portalSelectslist.FirstOrDefault(x => x.PortalId == item.PortalId);
if(temp != null)
{
    temp.AccessTypePortalId = item.AccesstypePortalId;
    temp.Isselected = true;
}
```

Comment: What if `temp` is null?

Comment: this question is not about exception handling. Anyway `if(temp !=null)` would be one option

Comment: I need to update aitem in the list.

Comment: that's what this code does. the `temp` is just a reference to the item in your list.